# Move search box and fix it into header when mouse scrolls down and bring back when move scrolls up

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a search box which I need to fix it into my bootstrap header when mouse is scrolled down >70px (or anything you consider) it should fix into it, and when mouse scrolled up it should come to top of page it should take its original position. here the demo to edit.[demoToEdit](http://jsfiddle.net/c29k6rba/). I have seen this in snapdeal.com. PLease help me to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

```
 [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/c29k6rba/
```

Comment: 1. I would post some of your code into your question as a lot of people are going to get mad because when you post a fiddle it tells you to post code etc.
2. Is there any other CSS? Or is it 100% bootstrap? Would you mind replacing the import with the bootstrap CSS code for easier manipulation

Comment: No css 100% bootstrap.

Comment: Show what you've tried so far.  SO isn't a place where people do your work for you.

Comment: @im1dermike I have tried using css but unable to fix that box into header thats why I put the code

Comment: If I put css which I have tried then its difficult for people who are ansering. One more thing I just want that search box to be fixed at top after scrolling mouse down nothing else. So for that do you except 100lines of css code from me??

Comment: And @im1dermike I am not expecting this could be done by people , then can provide me links to achieve the same. To down vote what I did wrong? I have provided fiddle if you know then edit it  else provide me link of any tutorials. The thing is I have min knowledge about css so I posted this.

Comment: You incorrectly linked the jsfiddle originally and I didn't see it.

Comment: I have marked demo please check it, before down voting read carefully

Answer (score 0):

Okay Well decided to take a quicker route with jquery instead of checking visibility I made ti just check scroll distance Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/c29k6rba/22/

Code:

```
 $('#searchBarSml').hide();
$(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(this).scrollTop()>0)
     {
        $('#searchBarSml').fadeIn();
        $('#searchBarLrg').fadeOut();
     }
    else
     {
      $('#searchBarLrg').fadeIn();
      $('#searchBarSml').fadeOut();
     }
 });
```

At the start the smaller bar is hidden and then on scroll it switches and vice versa. That should be what you want for real this time.

Comment: Yeah ofcourse I am using jquery, thanks for the response but this is not working properly as I can see search box  moves up, fits into header on mouse scroll down but doesnt comes back to its original position after mouse up. also not working at all for small devices.

Comment: I've updated my answer accordingly with more stable of a system to show you.